# Print the standard time - eg 04:52:06 PM - Bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have the

```
$ date +"%c"
```

command

which displays the date and time, however I only wish to display the time in full non military, eg: 04:52:06 PM

I have tried

```
date +"%T"
```

However that returns the Military Date, not standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try making it from "scratch" using all the options together. You can have as many in the format as you like.

```
]$ date +"%I:%M:%S %p"
05:26:22 PM
```

Comment: Ah, i actually did not think of doing it like that, fantastic

Answer (score 3):

Your system might accept `date +%r` that is an "alias" for `"%I:%M:%S %p"`

Answer (score 2):

I would display it in this way:

`date +"%I:%M:%S %p"`